# How can I convert a Bluetooth 16 bit service UUID into a 128 bit UUID?

Tags: bluetooth, uuid

All [assigned services](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx) only state the 16 bit UUID. How can I determine the 128 bit counterpart if I have to specify the service in that format?

From [Service Discovery Protocol Overview](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery) I know that 128 bit UUIDs are based on a so called "BASE UUID" which is also stated there:

```
00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

But how do I create a 128 bit UUID from the 16 bit counterpart? Probably some of the 0 digits have to be replaced, but which and how?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be found in the Bluetooth 4.0 Core spec **Vol. 3 - Core System**. See [the list of adopted specs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications).

In **Part B**, covering the **Service Discovery Protocol (SDP)** under **Chapter 2.5.1 "Searching for Services / UUID"** will explain how to calculate the UUID.

> The full 128-bit value of a 16-bit or 32-bit UUID may be computed by a simple arithmetic operation.
>
> ```
> 128_bit_value = 16_bit_value * 2^96 + Bluetooth_Base_UUID
> 128_bit_value = 32_bit_value * 2^96 + Bluetooth_Base_UUID
> ```
>
> A 16-bit UUID may be converted to 32-bit UUID format by zero-extending the 16-bit value to 32-bits. An equivalent method is to add the 16-bit UUID value to a zero-valued 32-bit UUID.

Note that, in another section, there's a handy mnemonic:

> Or, to put it more simply, the 16-bit Attribute UUID replaces the x’s in the follow-
>   ing:
>
> ```
> 0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
> ```
>
> In addition, the 32-bit Attribute UUID replaces the x's in the following:
>
> ```
> xxxxxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
> ```

---

The same equations go for attribute UUIDs. See **Part F**, covering the **Attribute Protocol (ATT)** under **Chapter 3.2.1 "Protocol Requirements / Basic Concepts"**. 32 bit attribute UUIDs are first specified in the Bluetooth Core 4.1 spec.

Comment: Is `0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` used in a context where a 16-bit UUID is known to be predefined by the specification? Or is that part of the 128-bit UUID an example of some kind?

Comment: @Cuadue, the `00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` is defined as the _Bluetooth_Base_UUID_ - see Bluetooth Core Specification 5.2 specification - Vol. 1, Part E, Section 2.5.1 UUID.