# how to know device's service uuid and characteristic uuid when connecting to bluetooth

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am developing a react native app that connect health device via bluetooth using the library

https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx

but after connecting I try to get service by calling `device.service()` but then there are an error saying no services discovered.

Now I am confused how I get service uuid and characteristic uuid to read data from bluetooth device. The device is glucose meter.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is no documentation available for a device one could use a BLE scanner app to scan for nearby devices and simply obtain the UUIDs that way.

There are multiple such apps available for both iOS and Android such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) and [LightBlue](https://punchthrough.com/lightblue/).

These can not only scan for BLE devices but can also be used to test them using simple read, write and notify operations.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i already got the answer service uuid of my device is
1808

i search it in here
https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf

i confirm it by log the device that show uuid of 00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

then base of this answer
[How can I convert a Bluetooth 16 bit service UUID into a 128 bit UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212020/how-can-i-convert-a-bluetooth-16-bit-service-uuid-into-a-128-bit-uuid)

i know how to read that 16bit uuid to 4 digit like this

> Or, to put it more simply, the 16-bit Attribute UUID replaces the x’s in the follow- ing:

> 0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
> In addition, the 32-bit Attribute UUID replaces the x's in the following:

> xxxxxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

then the characteristic uuid i think by documentation refer to 2A18 for the same name or description

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the documentation of this library
`Since Android 6 to scan the app needs to have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION runtime permission. Since Android 10 only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is accepted by the OS.`. You need to handle Android Runtime permissions.

Comment: already did that bro, after that i can connect but like library react-native-ble-plx documentation mentioned for function device.monitorCharacteristicForService(serviceUUID, characteristicUUID, listener)
need param of uuid service and character, from here i dont know where i can get this uuid for my device